# How to use Vuex namespaced getter with the Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-composition-api

I am currently trying to retrieve the `tags` in the Searchbar module from Vuex. However, it is not reactive.

Here is the component :

```html
<template>
  <div class="tags">
    <tag v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag.name">{{ tag.name }}</tag>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
import { defineComponent, computed } from '@vue/composition-api';
import store from '@/store/index';
import Tag from '@/components/BaseTag.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    Tag
  },
  setup() {
    const tags = computed(() => store.getters['Searchbar/all']);
    return {
      tags
    };
  }
});
```

and the vuex module

```js
import { Module, VuexModule, Mutation } from 'vuex-module-decorators';
import { TagType } from '@/enums';

type VuexTag = { name: string; type: TagType };

@Module({
  namespaced: true
})
export default class Searchbar extends VuexModule {
  private tagsInput: Array<VuexTag> = [];

  get all(): Array<VuexTag> {
    return this.tagsInput;
  }

  @Mutation
  addTag(tag: VuexTag): void {
    this.tagsInput[this.tagsInput.length] = tag;
  }

  @Mutation
  removeTag(index: number): void {
    this.tagsInput.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

I don't see why. I am using Typescript, and so it does not support the `store.Searchbar.getters['all'])`...
Got an idea ?

Comment: How does your VuexModule look like?

Comment: The wrapper should infer the type of property you are accessing (getter, mutation, action), so try to do:

store.getters.myModule.myGetter;

store.commit.myModule.myMutation(myPayload);

Comment: @AndreForonda returns : `Error in render: "TypeError: _store_index__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.getters.Searchbar is undefined"`. The `store.commit('Searchbar/addTag', { name: 'randomTag', type: TagType.NORMAL });` is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. My bad : it has nothing to do with the composition API. The above code is working concerning it.

In the Vuex module, I had to update the `addTag` mutation as follow :

```js
  @Mutation
  addTag(tag: SearchbarTag): void {
    Vue.set(this.tagsInput, this.tagsInput.length, tag);
  }
```

Basically array changes are not reactive by default, so we have to use the `Vue.set`method.